# Calculating OpenGL Face Normals of Polygon

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, normals

I am trying to add lighting to a polygon created from a point polygon file. My problem is when creating vectors from the points I only get a certain section of the polygons lit, then if I inverse the calculation for normals, (From A.x - C.x to C.x - A.x) it lights the section that was not previously lit. Code and pictures below.

[image: A.x - D.x]

[image: D.x - A.x]

```
 h_vector V1;//= (p2 - p1);
    // A = 0 B = 1 C = 2 D =3
    V1.x = vertices[1].x - vertices[0].x;
    V1.y = vertices[1].y - vertices[0].y;
    V1.z = vertices[1].z - vertices[0].z;


    h_vector V2;// = (p3 - p1);

    V2.x = vertices[3].x - vertices[0].x;
    V2.y = vertices[3].y - vertices[0].y;
    V2.z = vertices[3].z - vertices[0].z;
    /*

    h_vector V1;//= (p2 - p1);
    V1.x = vertices[0].x - vertices[1].x;
    V1.y = vertices[0].y - vertices[1].y;
    V1.z = vertices[0].z - vertices[1].z;


    h_vector V2;// = (p3 - p1);

    V2.x = vertices[0].x - vertices[3].x;
    V2.y = vertices[0].y - vertices[3].y;
    V2.z = vertices[0].z - vertices[3].z;
    */

    surfaceNormal.x = (V1.y*V2.z) - (V1.z-V2.y);
    surfaceNormal.y = - ( (V2.z * V1.x) - (V2.x * V1.z) );
    surfaceNormal.z = (V1.x-V2.y) - (V1.y-V2.x);
    float normalize = sqrtf((pow(surfaceNormal.x,2) + pow(surfaceNormal.y,2) + pow(surfaceNormal.z,2)));

    surfaceNormal.x = surfaceNormal.x/normalize;
     surfaceNormal.y = surfaceNormal.y/normalize;
     surfaceNormal.z = surfaceNormal.z/normalize;
```

Comment: Issue seems to be face culling, rather than normals, but need to see rest of the code before concluding. Not relevant, but normals calcuation can be done in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

This cross product code is badly broken:

```
surfaceNormal.x = (V1.y*V2.z) - (V1.z-V2.y);
surfaceNormal.y = - ( (V2.z * V1.x) - (V2.x * V1.z) );
surfaceNormal.z = (V1.x-V2.y) - (V1.y-V2.x);
```

The expressions within the parentheses should all have a multiplication operator, but half of them are subtractions instead in the code above.

The cross product calculation should be:

```
surfaceNormal.x = V1.y * V2.z - V1.z * V2.y;
surfaceNormal.y = V1.z * V2.x - V1.x * V2.z;
surfaceNormal.z = V1.x * V2.y - V1.y * V2.x;
```

You may want to look into using a matrix/vector library. There are many of them freely available if you do some searching.